# Edits required to be six or more characters

Tags: support, feature-request, status-bydesign, editing

I recently tried to correct an error in some example code but failed because I ran into the requirement that edits to posts must to be six or more characters. All I wanted to do was to add a missing "{". That was the only change that was needed. Is there a work-around for this? Even better, can it be eliminated?

Comment: Which post is this?

Comment: @J.M. it was [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13347/grid-item-alignment-to-decimal-problem/13348#comment38586_13348)

Comment: I reviewed that comment and it was mis-typed. The change should be from "{{" to "{", not the other way around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it can't be eliminated. The only way out is to reach 2k rep, at which point you earn the privilege to edit any post. This is in place so that low rep and anonymous users don't suggest trivial edits, burdening others with the task of reviewing them.

Usually, posts might need a bit more fixing than one character, but if indeed that single character is the only thing that needs fixing and you don't have sufficient rep, leave them a comment asking them to fix it.

Comment: I did leave such a comment. See my response to J.M.'s comment to my question. I look forward to achieving 2K+ rep :-)

Comment: I see from your profile you've started participating very recently and provided some pretty good answers already... you certainly will get to 2k (and more) in no time! Welcome to the community :)

Comment: Isn't it possible to just add some spaces somewhere? (I remember I had this problem once or twice before getting to 2k)

Comment: @Ajasja no, regular spaces are stripped out and don't count.  Try it with a comment, e.g. "x (ten spaces)"

Comment: Hmmm... I am pretty sure it worked for me once to just add spaces...